# Create Testing Data at Application Startup

Tags: java, spring, development-environment

We are developing ur Application with Spring Boot, and are currently creating our testing data at every run via our REST API. Now we want to create a "Bootstrap"-Script which should be run at startup and create all Objects which we need during development / Testing and so on.

I came from Grails where you simply had a Bootstrap class which can do this.

Now I modified our Application.java class to run a Method from another class, which should create our objects, but I cant inject our services inside there.

What would be the best solution to handle this situation?

Greetings
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Our Application Class we now have the following Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("spring.profiles.active="+System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active"));
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    System.out.println("Application Running!!!");

    autogenerateDatabaseTestdata(ctx);
}

private static void autogenerateDatabaseTestdata(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
    ctx.getBean(DataGenerator.class).run(ctx);
}
```

The DataGenerator looks like this:

```
@Component
public class DataGenerator {

    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String schemaDllHandling;

    @Value("${db.autogenerate_data}")
    private Boolean isAutogenerateData;

    public void run(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {

        if (isAutogenerateData == null || !isAutogenerateData || !"create".equalsIgnoreCase(schemaDllHandling)) {
            return; // Do nothing
        }

        System.out.println("Running Bootstrap:");
        ctx.getBean(CountryBootstrap.class).run();
        System.out.println("Bootstrap finished!");
    }
}
```

And for example the countryBootstrap looks like this:

```
@Component
public class CountryBootstrap {

    @Autowired
    CountryService countryService;

    public CountryBootstrap() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public CountryBootstrap(CountryService countryService) {
        this.countryService = countryService;
    }

    public void run() {
        countryService.saveCountry(new Country("Deutschland", "DE"));
    }
}
```

In our Application.yml we have a value which indicates if the Autogenerated Data should be imported or not:

```
db:
    autogenerate_data: true
```

Thats our Solution for Inserting TestData at the Startup of our Applicaation